# Sencha touch with XML

Tags: javascript, xml, ext.js

Could you please review the following?  My concern is XML parsing is hardcoded:

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: storageDataItem.contentlink,
        success: function (response) {
            var store;
            try {
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                // TODO: remove extra lines or ignore on parsing. How? :)
                var xml = parser.parseFromString(response.responseText, "text/xml");
                var mediaContentURL = response.responseXML.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].lastChild.attributes[0].nodeValue;
                var title = xml.getElementsByTagName('title')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            } catch (e) {
                // ignore exception
            }
            console.log("storage: ")
        }
    });
    this.fireEvent("playButtonTapped", storageDataItem);
    this.fireEvent("playAudioFile", title, mediaContentURL);
```

[The actual feed](http://audioserver.arn.com.au/getMediaPlaylist.aspx?MediaId=1834)

Answer (score 2):

From looking a little into this

- You derive `mediaContentURL` through `response.responseXML` and `title` through `xml`, I would stick in both cases to `xml`
- As you guessed, your approach to getting the mediaContentURL is pretty terrible.
- Use `getElementsByTagName` and `attributes`, do not hardcode array indexes
- Do not use `console.log` in production code

I would use something like this:

```
function getItemTitle( xml , itemNumber )
{
  //Skip the title number of the playlist
  return xml.getElementsByTagName('title')[itemNumber+1].textContent
}

function getItemURL( xml , itemNumber )
{
  return xml.getElementsByTagName('content')[itemNumber].attributes.getNamedItem('url').value;
}
```